# Java - scanner standing idle

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

Creating a java program that gets an input from the user, it must be of type 'byte' and in the interval [0,8].
I'm using a method to first check if the input is a byte, and then if thats true check if the byte fits in the interval and then return that value to my main method.

```
public static byte GetShiftedLeft(){
      byte l = GetByte(SHIFT_L_MSG);
      while (l < 0 || l > 8){
         System.out.println(l + " is not between the range");
         l = GetByte(SHIFT_L_MSG);
      }
      return l;
   }
   public static byte GetShiftedRight(){
      byte r = GetByte(SHIFT_R_MSG);
      while (r < 0 || r > 8){
         System.out.println(r + " is not between the range");
         r = GetByte(SHIFT_R_MSG);
      }
      return r;
   }
   public static byte GetByte(String prompt){
      System.out.print(prompt);
      Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
      while (!stdin.hasNextByte()){
         System.out.println("*** "+stdin.next() + " is not a byte ***");
         System.out.print("Try again\n"+prompt);
         stdin.next();
      }
      return stdin.nextByte();
   }
```

When I run the program to check it, if the first input is not a byte, but then the next input is a byte but doesn't fit in the interval, the message doesn't display and scanner stands idle.

Output run:

```
enter #left-shift bits in the interval [0,8]: 145
*** 145 is not a byte ***
Try again
enter #left-shift bits in the interval [0,8]: 12


4
enter #right-shift bits in the interval [0,8]: 12
12 is not between the range
enter #right-shift bits in the interval [0,8]: 11
11 is not between the range
enter #right-shift bits in the interval [0,8]: 10
10 is not between the range
enter #right-shift bits in the interval [0,8]: 789
*** 789 is not a byte ***
Try again
enter #right-shift bits in the interval [0,8]: 12
```

Then it just stands there...as lines 5 & 6 from the output

Comment: Why do you call `stdin.next()` twice?

Comment: I was calling it twice, the first time to print the input given telling the user it was not a byte, and the second one to tell the program to expect another input. As I understand now it can be done just with the first one and it works just fine

Answer (score 0):

You have stdin.next() twice, so when 789 is entered it expects another input, and then another one.

Answer (score 0):

A byte, according to the Oracle docs :

> is an 8-bit signed two's complement integer. It has a minimum value of -128 and a maximum value of 127 (inclusive)

So if you want to check if the value is a byte, you could use Scanner.nextInt() instead.

```
public boolean isByte(int n)
{
    if(n >= 128 && n <= 127)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public byte getByte()
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a byte here: ");
    int nextInt = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println();
    if(isByte(nextInt))
    {
        byte b = (byte) nextInt;
        if(b > 0 && b < 8)
        {
            System.out.println("Got byte "+b);
            return b;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Not in range [0,8]!! Try again!!");
            return getByte();
        }

    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Not a byte!! Try again!!");
        return getByte();
    }
}
```

Then if I understand your question correctly you are trying to bit shift that byte left or right by a given number n. Java has bit shift operators that make this doable in one line.

```
byte b = 105;
b << n; //bit shift n to the left
b >> n; //bit shift n to the right
```

Comment: Yeah that can work out, but I wanted the implementation to avoid all other inputs too, maybe the user inputs a string or a float...so it can print out the message to correct it. With yours is expecting an integer, it will need a throw to work as I want...

Comment: The reason I recommended an int is because a Java byte literally is an 8 bit integer. Of course this only works if you can assume that the input will always be an int. In the case you can't assume that, you can use `try{byte b = Byte.parseByte(scan.nextLine());}catch(NumberFormatException e){System.out.println("not a byte");}` This way you can always parse the data from the scanner and you can determine if it's a byte or not based on whether the exception gets thrown or not.